# Using array to create WHERE condition

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My function receives a array as parameter:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "usuario"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "john"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "senha"
  [3]=>
  string(40) "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "pessoa_id"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

What I need:

```
SELECT * FROM (`funcionarios`) WHERE `usuario` = 'john' AND `senha` = '7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b' AND `pessoa_id` = '2'
```

I need to create a WHERE with it, I'm using CodeIgniter and I came to this stupid but working solution:

```
foreach($params as $x) {
                if($pos%2==0)
                    $chave = $x;
                else
                    $valor = $x;
                $pos++;
                if($pos%2==0)
                    $this->db->where($chave, $valor);
            }
```

I'm trying to find something more user friendly because there will be another person using this code.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have any control over the array that gets passed in, do yourself a favor and turn it into an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this it the best way if you can't change that array. IF you can, do so now, because it's really inelegant

```
$data = array(
   "usuario" => "john",
   "senha" => "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b",
   "pessoa_id" => 2
);

foreach($params as $x => $y) {
      $this->db->where($x, $y);
}
```

Comment: yeah..I know..I'm reusing some code..if I change it, I'll have to change a lot of files...but if this solution I gave is the best...I'll change all =)

Comment: @Gerep yeah, absolutely worth it.

Comment: @Gerep you shouldn't be reusing code. That's what are functions for

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the format of the array, just use an associative array. For example:

```
array(

    "usuario" => "john" //etc.

);
```

Then you can take advantage of the `key` function in PHP to avoid your even index checking in the loop, or even change your loop to:

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value)
```

Comment: Yeah...I can do that but as I said to @Martin, I'll a lot of work doing that..but if changing the array is the best solution I'll do it

Comment: @Gerep I agree with Martin. completely - use an associative array format and change it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `funcionarios` WHERE ";
$wheres = array();

foreach ($paramas as $key => $val) {
    $wheres[] = "`$key`='$val'";
}

$query .= implode(' AND ', $wheres); // $query is now "SELECT * FROM `funcionarios` WHERE `myKey`='myValue' AND `otherkey`='otherval'";
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new proper associative array from the original. Then it's much easier.

```
$arr = array("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3");
$newArr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    $newArr[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + 1];
}
```

Then using foreach you can build your query.

Comment: Thanks but I'll use Martin and Evan solution, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Gerep I assumed you couldn't change the array, but if you can by all means do.

Comment: I can change but it will be a lot of work..so I was trying to avoid it.